# How to get ref of an array in PHP 5?

Tags: php, reference

In php 5, all variable and objects are passed by reference, but i can't get my codes work

My codes is:

```
$arrayA = array();

$array = $arrayA;
...
if(!in_array(thedata, $array)
    $array[] = thedata;
var_dump($arrayA);
```

The result is empty, am i missing something simple?

Comment: thanks to all, corrected a big mistake of mine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<?php
    $arrayA = array();
    $arrayB =& $arrayA;
    $arrayB = array(1,2,3);
    var_dump($arrayA);
```

Read more here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php (Search for Reference)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Answer (score 3):

Only objects are passed by reference. If you want to make a reference to simple types, you have to use =& for assignment:

```
php > $var1 = 'xxxxx';
php > $var2 =& $var1;
php > $var1 = 'yyyyy';
php > echo $var2;
yyyyy
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array =& $arrayA;
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP5 all objects are passed by reference (more or less), not all variables.

```
$array =& $arrayA;
```